# Why are my WordPress Websites Running so Slowly?

Tags: wordpress, server, centos6, plesk

I have a VPS that hosts about 20 relatively lightweight websites. Some are WordPress, some are Joomla and some are static HTML/CSS.

My problem is that the WordPress website are all running incredibly slowly - at times it can take up to a minute for a simple page load - occasionally it will just hang up entirely, although this is less often.

This happens in both front and back ends. I'm pretty sure it's not a template or theme issue, as even my custom themed WP sites are suffering from this problem.

I don't have an abundance of plugins installed, quite literally just a small handful of light plugins in some instances.

None of my other (non-WP) sites seem to have this issue. I'm not so great with the more intricate server stuff but have tried a few different things to try and address this (with no luck).

An example of a website I'm working on that currently suffers from this issue is http://dev.basilssandwiches.co.uk

Server Information
CPU         GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz
Version     Plesk v12.0.18
OS          CentOS 6.7

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are the WP databases on the same server?

Comment: Yes, the databases are on the same server, in the same hosting account as their associated websites.

Comment: A couple of things have helped me in the past. 1: Up the RAM on the server if you can afford it. I started with a 1gb droplet on Digital Ocean and slowly upgraded to the 4gb and it works a lot better, for obvious reasons. 2: Use W3 Total Cache, or something like it, to minimize database interactions and save yourself some PHP + MYSQL hassle. 3: Change settings in php.ini to increase memory_limit to something like 128MB. This can help Wordpress as some plugins need an extra bump. 4: Install Monit, or another monitoring application, on your server to check for issues. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest install nginx with the php-fpm on your server because with this server you will get better performance with your sites. We are using same setup for our client and it's working great